# (epson tm-t20ii) print multiple html files with qz-print

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I tried to print multiple html files in folder with qz-print and EPSON - TM-T20II, but seem no work.

This is an example of script that i used:

```
    function printPages() {
if (notReady()) {
  return;
}

qz.appendHTMLFile(getPath() + "misc/out-may-21.html");
qz.appendHTMLFile(getPath() + "misc/out-may-22.html");


while (!qz.isDoneAppending()) {
  qz.printHTML();
}
```

but it will only print "out-may-22.html" file.
- And one more problem, when printing html file, it print html file, then print one more text file with tag "".

So confused,
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:  Since QZ Tray 2.0, the new API supports a [data block which supports multiple HTML files](https://github.com/qzind/tray/wiki/2.0-pixel-printing#html-printing) without confusing callbacks.

For those still using QZ Print/QZ Tray 1.9, the function `qz.appendHTMLFile("...");` is not synchronous and cannot currently be called in succession.

Instead, you'll have to wait until `qzDoneAppending()` is called, then call `printHTML()`, then call `qz.appendHTMLFile("...");` again, etc.

```
<script>

   // Called automatically when the software has loaded
   function qzReady() {
      qz.findPrinter("epson");
   }

   // Called automatically when the software has finished searching for the printer
   function qzDoneFinding() {
       // append first file
       qz.appendHTMLFile("first.html");
   }

   var secondHasAppended= false;

   // Called automatically when a file is done appending
   function qzDoneAppending() {
       qz.print();
   }

   // Called automatically when document has been sent to the printer
   function qzDonePrinting() {
       if (!secondHasAppended) {
           qz.appendHTMLFile("second.html");
           secondHasAppended = true;
           // qzDoneAppending and qzDonePrinting will take care of the rest
       } else {
           alert("Done!");
       }
   }

</script>
```

If you require more than two documents, replace the boolean with a counter.

Answer (score 0):

I use QZTray 2.0.2 and I could not make it prints multi pages.

It only prints first page. In other words it only prints what it can render for only 1 page.

I have 3 pages HTML.

When I set "scaleContent" to false it only prints the one portion of first page. When I set it true it prints all pages into 1 page with scaling.

All I need is to print all pages one by one with scaling.

Best